# How to use custom font with python and tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I have a font called "Digital dream" and I'm trying to use it in a GUI that I made with python and tkinter, but the font won't change.

Here is my code:

```
# Creates the label that will display time passed
label = Label(root, text="0:00:00.000000", font=("Digital dream", 14))
label.grid(column=1, row=0)
```

If I change "Digital dream" to "Arial", for example, it works.

Comment: If you need a custom font you could always use an image of text, I know it's not convenient but that is the easiest option with tkinter. I think the easiest option is to change gui toolkits if you really need to use that font

Comment: What kind of font do you have?